# Connecting elements in separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to connect two arrays together, sort of.
I have two arrays, and want the elements of them to be sort of 'combined'.

So, let's say I have a scanner.
It gives me a value for each element in array1 (like US$).
I want it to return something (like a string, "this product is selling for cheap!") if that value for each element is less than or equal to the value in array2.

I'd only want it to link one item in an array to another in the *same position*.

Two arrays (mentioned above, briefly):

```
var array1 = [741, 451, 54188, 5847, 5418, 54944, 310, 541, 7451, 10211, 113, 9115, 62, 2841, 52482481, 24];
var array2 = [15, 418, 488, 130000, 8482, 55, 16, 14, 2546, 651, 4521, 11, 54, 659, 542, 1152];
```

So, 741 would be linked to 15, 451 to 418, 54188 to 488, etc.

After they were "linked", I would be able to see if the value (by value, I mean what my scanner finds for each one) for the element in array1 is equal to/less than the value for that element in array2.

For example, putting 741 into my scanner returns 16.
This is not less than 15, so wouldn't return anything.
- However, putting 451 into my scanner returns 417. This is less than 418, so it would return "this product is selling for cheap!"

**I hope this made sense.**

Comment: @zerkms I'm new to Javascript, and don't really understand .indexOf(). Would you be willing to explain?

Comment: @user3810560 - I'd suggest you get familiar with [MDN - linked here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) where you can lookup any javascript method or any javascript object type to see what methods it has.  [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is quite simple and fully described [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).  If you learn the good reference sources, then you should be able to find answers to much more info yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that just uses `.indexOf()` to lookup the product code in the first array and then use that index to look up a comparison price in the second array:

```
Product Number: <input id="testVal" type="text" value="741"><br>
Test Price: <input id="priceVal" type="text" value=15><br>
<button id="go">Lookup</button><br><br>
<div id="result"></div>

document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var prod = +document.getElementById("testVal").value;
    var price = +document.getElementById("priceVal").value;
    var result = lookupValue(prod, price);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
});


function lookupValue(prod, price) {
    var productCodes = [741, 451, 54188, 5847, 5418, 54944, 310, 541, 7451, 10211, 113, 9115, 62, 2841, 52482481, 24];
    var prices = [15, 418, 488, 130000, 8482, 55, 16, 14, 2546, 651, 4521, 11, 54, 659, 542, 1152];

    var index;
    if (!prod || !price) {
        return "Please Enter a Product Number and Price";
    }
    if ((index = productCodes.indexOf(prod)) >= 0) {
        if (index < prices.length && price < prices[index]) {
            return "This product is selling for cheap!";
        } else {
            return "This product is not a bargain.";
        }
    } else {
        return "Product not found for comparison";
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4S64t/.

---

With this many product codes, there really no issue with just using `.indexOf()` to find a match in the first array.  But, if you had lots of product codes, then it would be much faster to index them once into an object for direct lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead create an object and put that in a single array.

```
var my Obj = {no1:741, no2:15, text:'some text'}
```

That would let you build the array without the need for a scanner since it's already stored in the "scanned" state

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript object, which works like a dictionary (or hashmap)

```
var myObj = {};
array1.forEach(function(item, i) {
    myObj[item] = array2[i];
});
alert(myObj[741]);
>>> 15
```

In such arrangement, the array1 contains `keys`, and array 2 contains `values` of your dictionary.